# Why does SEG not give an error message with this code fragment?

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

The line below has no error generated by the assembler:

```
mov ax,seg TEXT:frewd
```

*(see program fragment below)*

I would expect the assembler to create a error message because `frewd` is not in the `TEXT` segment but is in the `TEXT1` segment and no `GROUP` statement exists.

Am I missing something?

I have filled both segments with dummy data so that there are 2 different segments but still no error.

```
 .386
 TEXT segment para private
   example dw ?
   dummy byte 65531 dup(0)
   sample dw ?
 TEXT ends
 TEXT1 segment word private 'CODE'
   frew dw ?
   dummy1 byte 65531 dup(0)
   frewd dw ?
 TEXT1 ends
 Cseg segment
   mov ax, seg TEXT:frewd ;no error is generated here by the assembler
   mov es,ax
 Cseg ends
 end
```

Comment: It probably put TEXT and TEXT1 in the same segment? Or the assembler is not smart enough to do such checks.

Comment: How can it put both segments in the same segment? I thought the max size per segment was 65535? Am I wrong about that?

Comment: Oh, it would be two different blocks both using the same segment register with two different values. I just think that the assembler is not smart enough to detect the problem.

Comment: The problem that occurs is that you will not notice the wrong segment is being used and will be hard to detect. I tried it using .8086 instead of .386 and still got no error message. There should be a error message for this.

Comment: I'm so glad that x86-16 is obsolete so we don't have to use quirky old toolchains or segmentation anymore.

Comment: No, there shouldn't be an error message for this because `TEXT:...` is a segment override, and so the whole point of it is to tell the assembler to override the segment of `frewd`.  The problem is that you're using a segment override when it's not necessary, you can just do `mov ax, seg frewd`.  Not that it actually makes any difference because as it turns out the SEG operator ignores the segment override and evaluates to `TEXT1`, the segment of `frewd` anyways. In any case you should only use segment overrides when the left side is a segment register and/or when the right side is a number.

Comment: Ross, you say that TEXT: is a segment override but according to masm their documentation says this: The SEG operator returns a variables "Frame" if it appears in the instruction. The frame is the value of the segment, group or segment override of a nonexternal variable. They then give the example "mov ax, SEG DGROUP:VAR"  and then state For example the instruction places in AX the value of DGROUP where VAR is located.  (continued below).

Comment: Based on that example "mov AX, seg TEXT:frewd" should be place in AX the value of TEXT where "frewd" is located but "frewd" in not in the segment "TEXT" it is located in "TEXT1". Your explaination does not match masm's documentation. Please explain in more detail. How does "seg TEXT" become "seg TEXT1"?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an error when you _link_ though? I didn't test this with MASM, but with TASM/TLINK the assembler would just output a placeholder `mov ax,0` machine code sequence, and then when I tried to link I got `Error: Fixup overflow at CSEG:0002, target = TEXT1:0006`

Comment: DGROUP is a group, not a segment. Despite what the documentation says, MASM's behaviour is different depending on whether a segment override uses the name of a segment or a name of a group.  **Regardless, none of this matters**.  If you want the segment of `frewd` just use `mov ax, SEG frewd`, if you want the TEXT segment instead just use `mov ax, TEXT`.

Comment: @Michael TASM's behaviour is different than MASM's. The segment override actually does change the frame of used for frewd, so the linker ends up using the offset of frewd relative to the base of TEXT rather than TEXT1. MASM doesn't do this, instead the frame of frewd doesn't change so the linker uses the offset of frewd relative to the base of TEXT1. (Although I'm not sure why the linker complains about the first relocation as the offset part doesn't matter.)

Comment: Ross, So if I understand correctly: If a segment name is before the symbol masm ignores it and uses the segment value of the symbol. But that does not explain if I have a group created DGROUP that is composed of TEXT and TEXT1 and then add a new segment TEXT2 that is not part of the group and TEXT2 contains SAMPLE2 and add to the CSEG segment this "mov ax, DGROUP:SAMPLE2".When I assemble it I get no error for SAMPLE2 not in DGROUP.

Comment: Ross, what is the correct rule for SEG when a group, segment or segment override is before a symbol?

Comment: `DGROUP` isn't a segment name, its a group name and using it as an override changes the frame to be `DGROUP`.  The offset used to access `SAMPLE2` relative to the base of `DGROUP`.  It doesn't matter if the segment `SAMPLE2` belongs to isn't part of `DGROUP`, as you've overridden this by using `DGROUP` as a segment override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for MASM to give an error for this line.  The SEG operator obtains the segment address (paragraph address in real mode) of the frame of the expression it's used on.  A frame is the segment or group that the final offset of an address is determined relative to by the linker.  By default the frame of an address is the same as the segment of address, unless the segment of the address belongs in a group.  Note that this means addresses in MASM have three parts, a frame, a segment, and an offset.

Since `TEXT:frewd` is an address, that means it has a frame, so the SEG operator evaluates to the frame of that expression.  As it turns out the frame of the expression `TEXT:frewd` isn't what it would appear to be, but if it were actually `TEXT`, there would be no reason why MASM couldn't evaluate the expression without error.  The problem of `frewd` not being within 64k of the base of `TEXT` isn't something that would be known until link time.

MASM only allows the frame of an address to be different from the segment of an address if the frame is group.  This means that when a segment name is used as a segment override of label, it doesn't actually change the frame of the address to be the named segment.  Instead, the frame get changed to that of label's segment if the frame used to be a group, otherwise the frame remains the same as label's segment.  However the segment override does change what segment register MASM will use for the instruction, based on previous ASSUME statements, if the label is used in a memory operand.

I've created an example to try to demonstrate how MASM behaves.  Each MOV instruction that loads a value from memory is commented with a description of what segment register ("sreg") the assembler uses for the instruction, and the frame and segment that are used for the address of the memory operand.  The frame and segment used appear in the relocations (or fixups) that the assembler puts in the object file it outputs.

```
DATA1   SEGMENT PARA
data1_label DW  0
DATA1   ENDS

DATA2   SEGMENT PARA
    DW  2
data2_label DW  4
DATA2   ENDS

DGROUP  GROUP   DATA1, DATA2

FARDATA SEGMENT PARA
    DW  6, 8
fardata_label DW 10
FARDATA ENDS

CODESEG SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
start:
    mov ax, DGROUP
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, FARDATA
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, DATA2
    mov ss, ax
    ASSUME  ds:DGROUP
    ASSUME  es:FARDATA
    ASSUME  ss:DATA2
    ASSUME  cs:CODESEG

    ; Since data1_label and data2_label belong to segments that belong to DGROUP,
    ; they're accessed relative to DGROUP by default and through the segment 
    ; register assumed to point to DGROUP. The correct code is generated
    ; without any overrides.

    mov ax, [data1_label]           ; sreg: DS, frame: DGROUP,  segment: DATA1
    mov ax, [data2_label]           ; sreg: DS, frame: DGROUP,  segment: DATA2

    ; No surprises here, fardata_label is accessed relative to the segment its
    ; defined in and using the segment register assumed for that segment.

    mov ax, [fardata_label]         ; sreg: ES, frame: FARDATA, segment: FARDATA

    ; Changing the last three instructions to use DATA2 as a segment override causes
    ; them all to use the SS segment register, the one assumed for SS.  It also
    ; overrides using DGROUP as the frame for data1_label and data2_label, but
    ; doesn't change the frame to DATA2 for either data1_label or fardata_label.
    ; Only the second instruction will work correctly.  The other two instructions
    ; use the wrong segment register access the label at the offset the linker will
    ; end up using.

    mov ax, [DATA2:data1_label]     ; sreg: SS, frame: DATA1,   segment: DATA1
    mov ax, [DATA2:data2_label]     ; sreg: SS, frame: DATA2,   segment: DATA2
    mov ax, [DATA2:fardata_label]   ; sreg: SS, frame: FARDATA, segment: FARDATA

    ; Overriding with CODESEG has the same as effect as overriding with DATA2,
    ; except the CS register is used instead. None of the instructions will
    ; work, since none of them will have offsets relative to CODESEG, the segment
    ; loaded into CS.

    mov ax, [CODESEG:data1_label]   ; sreg: CS, frame: DATA1,   segment: DATA1
    mov ax, [CODESEG:data2_label]   ; sreg: CS, frame: DATA2,   segment: DATA2
    mov ax, [CODESEG:fardata_label] ; sreg: CS, frame: FARDATA, segment: FARDATA

    ; Using DGROUP as an override on fardata_label will work so long as
    ; fardata_label doesn't end up getting placed before the start of the DGROUP,
    ; or someplace 64K beyond the start of DGROUP.  If it does end up outside
    ; DGROUP then the linker will give an error.  The assembler is unable to
    ; detect this.

    mov ax, [DGROUP:fardata_label]  ; sreg: DS, frame: DGROUP,  segment: FARDATA

    ; Using a single segment override on a number works as expected, but 
    ; using multiple overrides only the left-most override has an effect. 

    mov ax, [CODESEG:0]             ; sreg: CS, frame: CODESEG, segment: CODESEG
    mov ax, [DGROUP:0]              ; sreg: DS, frame: DGROUP,  segment: DGROUP
    mov ax, [DGROUP:CODESEG:0]      ; sreg: DS, frame: DGROUP,  segment: DGROUP
    mov ax, [CODESEG:DGROUP:0]      ; sreg: CS, frame: CODESEG, segment: CODESEG
    mov ax, [FARDATA:CODESEG:0]     ; sreg: ES, frame: FARDATA, segment: FARDATA
CODESEG ENDS

    END start
```

If you change MOV instructions so that they use SEG on the address (eg. `mov ax, SEG data1_label` or `mov ax, SEG DATA2:data1_label`) then SEG operator will evaluate to whats given as the "frame" in the comments.

The moral of the story is that you almost never want to use to segment names as segment overrides with MASM, as it almost certainly won't do what you want.  There's also rarely any need to to use group names as segment overrides as the assembler will use the group by default for anything defined in a group.  (Note this was different with MASM 5 or earlier where you had to use `OFFSET DGROUP:label` if the label was part of DGROUP in order to get the right result.)

The only really useful way to use segment overrides with MASM is when a segment register is used on the left hand side.  In that case, it can be an alternative to using ASSUME or when there's no label involved in a memory operand, like with indexed addressing (eg. `mov ax, es:[di]`).

Comment: Ross, I am still trying to digest all the information that you gave on this subject. Thank you. So if I understand correctly the assembler does not know where the position of the segment TEXT is to know if segment TEXT1 combined with TEXT would exceed 64k. However if I create all the segments as "dummy" segments before using them (forcing them to be in order) the assembler still does not give a error and it should since it keeps track of the segment sizes. It should detect it before link time.

Comment: @StillLearning I think you missed the main point here.  There's no error to detect here because SEG obtains the frame of an expression and the frame of the expression `TEXT:frewd` is TEXT1.

Comment: Ross, I tried to assemble the example code you posted and got 3 error messages, all the same error message: Error A2004:symbol type conflict. This error message occurs for these instructions:mov ax, DGROUP on line 20,  mov ax, FARDATA on line 22, and mov ax, DATA2 on line 24. But they only happen if I try to assemble using the /coff switch. Any idea how to do it using the /coff switch? I want to see any link error messages and it needs to assemble using the /coff to link it.

Comment: Ross, In your example that you posted when the SS segment is assigned the DATA2 segment and later the 2 different instructions  mov ax, [DATA2:data1_label] and mov ax, [DATA2:fardata_label]. From what you are saying masm does not detect this error does the linker?

Comment: @StillLearning Using the `/coff` switch doesn't make sense given your question.  PECOFF objects are only useful for creating 32-bit flat model executables that run under Windows.  You can't change the segment registers, and the SEGMENT directive creates sections, rather than segments. These sections aren't limited to 64K and can be up to 2G in size.  There are no errors in my example code (when compiled with `/omf`) for the assembler or linker to detect. The code does what MASM is supposed to do, even if it's not what you think it should do.

Comment: Ross, Is the following correct for the rule for a "SEG SegmentName:SymbolName" for a instruction that allows it: The SegmentName is verifed that it exists but is not used. The frame is determined from the SymbolName. The segment that the symbolName resides in is the segment address for SEG, its frame. What would be the rule for "SEG GroupName:SegmentName:Symbol"? Masm accepts this. I tried it and no error from masm.

Comment: Ross, You were correct about there being no errors in your example. I was wrong I had my settings wrong for the linker to use. Sorry to offend you. When I did link your program, with the correct linker, I got no errors.That shows me it is very easy to make a mistake in your program by using segment names for overrides and not even discovering them until you use a debugger to check your final code. I am working on the rule to use for SEG. Since I now know that the information in masm for SEG is wrong.

Comment: Ross, If I add the following 3 lines to your listing and assemble them I get no error. I would expect that I should get a error message for each line. Am I wrong to expect a error for each line? Here are the lines: "mov ax, seg DGROUP:FARDATA:Fardata_label" "mov ax, seg DGROUP:FARDATA:data2_label" "mov ax ,seg DGROUP:Fardata_label"